google image seach api shows bad results
my problem is that the google image api is giving me bad results
e.g. https://cse.google.com/cse?cx=b681a36ce88a24e6b#gsc.tab=1&gsc.q=banana&gsc.sort=
This is how i use it in code
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={apiKey}&cx={searchEngineId}&q={query}&searchType=image
but the result is the same as in the cse.google.com link
Search the entire Web is ON
I want normal results like when I use it in the browser.
Any ideas? :)

What do you mean by "bad results" ? What is expected ? [what you are asking]

I think my banana exmaple was not that good. Here is a better one:
https://cse.google.com/cse?cx=b681a36ce88a24e6b#gsc.tab=1&gsc.q=Taula%20de%20formatges%20de%20la%20terra&gsc.sort=
vs.
https://www.google.de/search?q=Taula+de+formatges+de+la+terra + go to image
The first search is useless results..

@julian have the same issue, did you find cause?

@DenysIsaev no, did you? its crazy to me that this is the case. this api has to be used by so man ppl. im so clueless.. :/
